# Android WebView automatically loading index.html

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm creating an android webview that loads a simple html page:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/external/login.html");
```

But for some reason, when the page loads it is loading http://10.0.2.2/external/index.html all the time, even if I explicitly specify a different html page such as login.html above.  I'm running a simple http server at http://10.0.2.2/ (my local machine).  Is there a setting somewhere that causes this?  How can I make it load the page I want it to and not index.html?

Thanks.

Comment: posts the code of your login.html page.

Comment: It could be annything - TEST <br> TEST - happens no matter what

Comment: Actually it doesn't happen without this - webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); But it needs javascript - any way around that?

Comment: ok check my answer and show us the code of the login.html page.

Comment: See below.  Redirect problem in javascript - not a problem with android or android studio etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually it doesn't happen without this -
>   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Probably your web pages contain a script to redirect to `index.html`, like :

```
window.location = " http://10.0.2.2/external/index.html ";
```

Comment: This ended up being a redirect problem with the javascript that I thought was inherently tied to android studio or android but was incorrect.  It wasn't exactly as simple as the location=? but it wasn't really auto-selecting the index.html as I thought it was.